# Запятая перед союзом "либо" между группами однородных членов

Tags: запятые, союзы, однородные-члены

*Вспомни, как в последний раз ты узнал о каком-то деле, изучил его и отложил на потом(,) либо начал его делать и не выполнил до конца.*

Союз "либо" одиночный — запятая не ставится, даже несмотря на то, что разделяет группы однородных членов? Верно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Верно. Первая группа однородных сказуемых ("узнал, изучил и отложил") соединена *одиночным союзом **либо*** с другой группой ("начал делать и не выполнил"), поэтому запятая перед ним не требуется:
**Вспомни, как в последний раз ты узнал о каком-то деле, изучил его и отложил на потом либо начал его делать и не выполнил до конца.**

Разделительный союз [**либо**](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/370/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE) указывает на необходимость выбора одного из понятий, выражаемых однородными членами и исключающих или заменяющих друг друга, например:

*Помочь нельзя было, так она ухаживала за страдальцем: кормила его с ложки, как младенца, меняла белье, водила по нужде и в затхлый маленький чуланчик старалась напустить свежего воздуху, а в остальное время **раскладывала** пасьянс **либо** беспредметно и молча по нескольку раз **обходила** пустые комнаты, **чистила, прибирала**, сама **подметала и мыла** пол* (Л. Андреев. Ипатов).