# Запятая перед «как»: нужна или нет?

Tags: запятые, обороты-с-как

Нужна или нет запятая перед «как» в предложениях «Танцуй как в последний раз», «Она выходила на бой как в последний раз»?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запятая перед союзом "либо" между группами однородных членов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440101/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%8e%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Какой же дубликат - это запятая перед КАК в сравнительном обороте , а там запятая в предложениях  с однородными членами?

Comment: В теме "запятая пере союзом как"  дубликаты практически невозможны. Там каждое предложение требует индивидуального подхода и решения.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, однозначного ответа мы не найдём. Смотря с каких позиций смотреть. *Как в последний раз* - это, конечно, устойчивое сочетание со значением "ярко, с полной отдачей, на 100% выложиться", хотя ни в одном фразеологическом словаре его нет. В предложении выполняет функцию обстоятельства образа действия, обозначает признак действия. Однако если взглянуть на смысл фразы, это не метафора, это скорее сравнение. И *выходила на бой, как в последний раз*- выходила так яростно, как выходят в последний раз, и *танцуй, как последний раз* - так, как танцуют в последний раз. А если есть сравнение - это сравнительный оборот. Вот В.Луговой в тексте песни, которую поёт Нани Брегвадзе, обособляет оборот как сравнительный.

> Эта осень
>
> К нам с тобой
>
> Сошла с картины,
>
> Лёгкой нитью паутины
>
> Вновь связала нас.
>
> День прозрачный
>
> Полон света золотого,
>
> На меня ты смотришь снова,
>
> Как в последний раз.
>
> Мы друг друга
>
> Ни о чём с тобой
>
> Не спросим,
>
> Догорая в листьях осень
>
> Нам даёт наказ.
>
> Грусть напрасна
>
> Потому, что
>
> Жизнь прекрасна,
>
> Если ты живёшь и любишь,
>
> Как в последний раз.
>
> Если любишь,
>
> Как в последний раз.

Мне тоже хочется поставить запятую. А вот на сайтах используют этот оборот в качестве названия страницы без запятой: Танцуй как последний раз. Я не думаю, что это ошибка, это скорее способ привлечь внимание к странице, здесь явно значение "не просто танцуй, а танцуй ярко и зрелищно", обстоятельство тесно примыкает к сказуемому. Видимо, это тоже корректно.

Так что бывает так, что устойчивый оборот сохраняет и значение сравнения, тогда он обособляется, а бывает - на первое место выходит тесная связь со сказуемым, тогда обособление не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Я полагаю, что здесь возможны **СМЫСЛОВЫЕ ВАРИАНТЫ.**

**Вариант 1.** Обособление оборота: **значение УПОДОБЛЕНИЯ,** можно использовать союзы СЛОВНО, БУДТО, КАК БУДТО

***ТанцУй**,  как в последний раз.  Она выходила **на бОй**, как в последний раз.*

В обоих случаях смысл просматривается ясно: делать так хорошо, с такой самоотдачей, **как будто** ты это делаешь в последний раз.

Этот смысл можно выразить, только обособив сравнительный оборот.

**Вариант 2.** Необособленный оборот: **ОПРЕДЕЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ значение** "танцуй так, как ты танцевала в последний раз, на последнем выступлении".

Такой вариант более характерен для **сложного** предложения,например:

*Танцуй  **как в последний рАз**, когда ты получила высокую ценку* (по той же методике, с теми же приемами).

А вот во втором предложении возможно тоько уподобление и обособление оборота: *Она выходила на бОй, как в последний раз.*

Например: Она **всегда** выходила на бой, как в последний раз. Она выходила на **этот** бой, как в последний раз.

Имеется в виду: с таким настроением, с такой самоотдачей, как будто бой был последний.